# Como llamar un unico valor del json, ejemplo el nombre (el json tiene id, nombre, apellido, etc)

Tags: javascript, json

```
    fs.readFile("user.json", function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data.toString());
});
```

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow. Todo depende de la estructura de tu JSON, pon un ejemplo del mismo.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías utilizar JSON.parse, algo así:

```
fs.readFile("user.json", function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    obj = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(obj.nombre);
});
```

¡Suerte!